# How to link in a chart the title, and the axis labels to cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When preparing charts, it is possible to assign the name of the series to represent to a cell. Is it possible to do it also for other parameters of a chart such as the chart title or the axis labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can set the chart title to reflect the value shown in a cell.

After building your chart, select the title box. Then with the title box selected, click in the formula bar, then select the cell you'd like for your title.  The cell's title will now be a formula such as "=Sheet1!:$A$1"

And, of course, you can set cell $A$1 's value to be as elaborate a concatenation of strings and cell values as you'd like.

Comment: You will need to type an `=` (equals sign) or a `+` (plus sign) before clicking the cell, otherwise nothing happens.